# How to avoid quartz starting when grail application start

Tags: grails, groovy, quartz-scheduler

I have a simple application in GRAILS which use Quartz2 plugin.
In the job file I have:

```
static triggers = {
    simple repeatCount: 0 // execute job once in 5 seconds
    cron cronExpression: '0 15 2 * * ?'
}

def execute() {
    if (Environment.current == Environment.PRODUCTION)
        do something...
}
```

Everything works fine in this case, if it's not in production the trigger is ignored.
Now the question is simple, if I start the application in the production the jobs starts as soon as the grails fire up. I wish to avoid the job running asap the app starts,but only when is correctly set in the cronExpression.

Any idea?

UPDATE:
At the end I put this line in config.groovy:

```
environments {
    development {
       grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
       grails.plugin.quartz2.autoStartup = false
    }
    production {
      grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
  }  
}
```

Now it seems not to start at the bootstrap I have to do a couple of test more and I let you know.

thank you

UPDATE2:
Ok now the schedule doesn't start at all, I was expecting that it starts but don't execute the jobs scheduled but wait the right time to trigger it. Any help?

thanks a lot

UPDATE3:
Sorry but I feel really stupid, adding simple repeatCount:0 fire once at start up, so deleting that it works perfect, sorry again.

Answer (score 5):

By setting up `conf\QuartzConfig.groovy`, you can control which environments that job sceduling automaically starts. For example:

```
quartz {
    autoStartup = true
    jdbcStore = false
    waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown = true
}

environments {
    development {
        quartz {
            autoStartup = false
        }
    }
}
```

In your `jobs` class, you can also set a `startDelay` on your trigger

```
static triggers = {
    cron name: 'myTrigger', startDelay: 5000, cronExpression: '0 15 2 * * ?'
}
```

Comment: Hi GeoGriffin, thank yu for your answer. I add the file under configuration, and copy and paste your settings line, but nothing. When I start the grails application, I put a printline in the execute() method, I see the line printed so for some reason it still run even if I'm in development environment and set atuostartup false. I'm using Grails 2.1 and quartz2 version 2.2. I see there is version 2.3 I'll try to update and see. thanks again

Comment: Just install version 2.3 same issue :(

Comment: If you have the Quartz Monitor installed (`grails install-plugin quartz-monitor`), then you should be able to go to `/quartz/list` to see which jobs you have configured and the state of the Quartz process.

Comment: This would be at something like... `http://your-server.your-company.com:your-port/your-app/quartz/list`

Comment: Hi Geo, well I'm using quartz2, quartzmonitor seems to be available only for quartz1

Comment: I had the same problem with it being ignored when I set it up in the Config.groovy file, but when I created conf\QuartzConfig.groovy like you suggested, it worked great!! Thanks